# Fastest Implementation of Dijkstra Algorithm in R

Tags: r

I have a below R code. The code works fine in computing shortest path between minimal input. If my input is big the code throws error in my coding environment.

Is there a way to fine tune the below code **to achieve faster implementation**. Suggestions/Corrections are highly appreciable.

Note : I am trying to implement without external packages

```
input <- suppressWarnings(readLines(stdin(), n=7))
5 6
1 2 30
1 3 10
5 2 40
3 5 20
5 1 30
5 4 20
l1 <- unlist(strsplit(input[1]," "))
 cities <- as.numeric(l1[1])
 roads <- as.numeric(l1[2])

L <- matrix(100000000,cities,roads)
#L <- format(L,scientific = FALSE)

distance <- function(inp){
   f <- unlist(strsplit(input[inp+1]," "))
   m <- as.numeric(f[1])
   n <- as.numeric(f[2])   
   L[m,n] <<- as.numeric(f[3])

}
invisible(mapply(distance,seq_along(1:roads ))) 
 

if(cities > dim(L)[2])
{
 cat("NOT POSSIBLE")
 
} else {
n=length(L[,1])
v=1
dest=n
cost=L

dijkstra = function(n, v, cost, dest) {
  dest = numeric(n)
  flag = numeric(n)
  prev = numeric(n)
  
  dstv <- function(i){
    prev[i] <<- -1
    dest[i] <<- cost[v, i]
  }
  invisible(mapply(dstv,seq_along(1:n)))  
  
  count = 2
  while (count <= n) {
    min = 100000000
    
   destw <- function(w) {
      if (dest[w] < min && !flag[w]) {
        min <<- dest[w]
        u <<- w
      }
    }
    invisible(mapply(destw,seq_along(1:n))) 
        
    flag[u] = 1
    count = count + 1     

    destu <- function(w) {
      if ((dest[u] + cost[u, w] < dest[w]) && !flag[w]) {
        dest[w] <<- dest[u] + cost[u, w]
        prev[w] <<- u
      }
    }   
    invisible(mapply(destu,seq_along(1:n)))     
  }
  return(prev)
}

savepath = function(f, x) {
  path = x
  while (f[x] != -1) {
    path = c(path, f[x])
    x = f[x]
    savepath(f, x)
  }
  path = c(path, 1)
  return(path)
}

prev = dijkstra(n,v,cost,dest)
path = sort(savepath(prev,dest))
 
}
```

Comment: How big is big and what error message is thrown?

Comment: cities input constraint is from 1 to 50,000 and roads is 1 to 500,000.  I have to compute the minimum shortest path for any given input in less than 2 seconds.

Comment: And the error thrown?

Comment: "time exceeded limit". its not an R error. its a custom error of the coding environment.

Comment: the `less than 2 seconds`, and how many cities & roads were under consideration when time was exceeded? I'm guessing you're going to solve your time problem by instituting some sort of `lookup table` approach where if City A and City B are under consideration, a whole range of roads need not be considered at all.

Comment: Cities and roads are dynamic input here. Assume 50,000 cities and 500,000 roads are given as input . I need to find shortest distance between any selected cities. The code is not able to handle that much big input in our coding Environment.